# phpize Imagick build fails: missing functions

Tags: linux, php, debian

I am trying to install Imagick on my Debian 10 server running php 7.4 but it looks like some functions are missing from my system.

I installed `sudo apt install php7.4-dev`

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.12
PHP Version: 7.4.11
Zend Engine Version: 3.4.0
Running on: Linux 4.19.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17) x86_64

phpize7.4 -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

here is `sudo pecl install imagick`

```
downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
.....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
19 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
configure.ac:161: warning: LTOPTIONS_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: LTSUGAR_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: LTVERSION_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: LTOBSOLETE_VERSION is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
build/libtool.m4:61: LT_INIT is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:99: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure:4702: error: possibly undefined macro: m4_ifval
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:8297: error: possibly undefined macro: _LT_SET_OPTIONS
configure:8297: error: possibly undefined macro: LT_INIT
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

here is my `/usr/share/libtool/configure.ac`

```
## ------------------------ ##
## Autoconf initialisation. ##
## ------------------------ ##
AC_INIT([libltdl], [2.4.3a], [bug-libtool@gnu.org])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h:config-h.in])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([ltdl.c])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([../build-aux])
LT_CONFIG_LTDL_DIR([.]) # I am me!


## ------------------------ ##
## Automake Initialisation. ##
## ------------------------ ##

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([gnu subdir-objects])
m4_ifdef([AM_SILENT_RULES], [AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])])


## ------------------------------- ##
## Libtool specific configuration. ##
## ------------------------------- ##
pkgdatadir='$datadir'"/$PACKAGE"


## ----------------------- ##
## Libtool initialisation. ##
## ----------------------- ##
LT_INIT([dlopen win32-dll])
_LTDL_SETUP


## -------- ##
## Outputs. ##
## -------- ##
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Why are you building it yourself instead of just installing the package?

Comment: what am I missing please which package are you talking about?

Comment: The `php-imagick` package included with Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `php-dev` installed on your server ? If not, try to run `sudo apt install php-dev`

Comment: hi, installed with `sudo apt install php7.4-dev` as mentioned in the question. `php-dev` if for PHP 5.xx versions I think

Comment: php-dev exist for every version of php and required to run phpize because it's inside the package. Do you have any return while doing the `phpize7.4 -v` command?

Comment: yes `phpize7.4 -v` seems fine, I also tried `apt install php7.4-dev` but no change; still the same error

Comment: Okay, if you only use the same command but with only `phpize -v` without adding the 7.4 is it working ?

Comment: yes all working

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a buggy version of `apt install php7.4-dev` see answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039093/phpize-imagick-build-fails-missing-functions?noredirect=1#comment1352594_1039093)